# Calling a method on OnClick using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TS code like this:

```
class MicrositeRequest {
    micrositeName: string;
    micrositeTemplate: string;

    constructor() {
        this.micrositeName = $("#micrositeNameId").val();
        this.micrositeTemplate = $("#templateId option:selected").text();
    }

  public  IsMicrositeRequestValid() {
        if (this.checkForName() && this.checkForTemplate()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    checkForName() {
        if (this.micrositeName != null && this.micrositeName.length != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    checkForTemplate() {
        if (this.micrositeTemplate != null && this.micrositeTemplate.length != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the converted JS:

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
var MicrositeRequest = (function () {
    function MicrositeRequest() {
        this.micrositeName = $("#micrositeNameId").val();
        this.micrositeTemplate = $("#templateId option:selected").text();
    }
    MicrositeRequest.prototype.IsMicrositeRequestValid = function () {
        if (this.checkForName() && this.checkForTemplate()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    MicrositeRequest.prototype.checkForName = function () {
        if (this.micrositeName != null && this.micrositeName.length != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    MicrositeRequest.prototype.checkForTemplate = function () {
        if (this.micrositeTemplate != null && this.micrositeTemplate.length != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    return MicrositeRequest;
})();

//# sourceMappingURL=Microsite.js.map
```

On Click of a button I want to call the `IsMicrositeRequestValid()` method.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get" onclick="IsMicrositeRequestValid()" />
        </div>
```

The Console says `IsMicrositeRequestValid` is not defined.

Any clues why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The call to `IsMicrositeRequestValid` in the `onclick` attribute requires that the function be part of the global namespace (`window`). Further, I'm pretty sure you'll need to instantiate `MicrositeRequest` object before the call to `IsMicrositeRequestValid` work (because it relies on `this`).

```
function validateRequest() { // declare a function in the global namespace
    var mr = new MicrositeRequest();
    return mr.IsMicrositeRequestValid();
}

<input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Get" onclick="validateRequest()" />
```

is the quick & dirty way which should get it working.

You could also do this:

```
window.validateRequest = function () { // declare a function in the global namespace
    var mr = new MicrositeRequest();
    return mr.IsMicrositeRequestValid();
}
```

which I think is more readable.

Also, look into the `Element.addEventListener` method. It allows much more flexibility.

```
var submit = document.getElementById('my-submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var mr = new MicrositeRequest();
    return mr.IsMicrositeRequestValid();    
});

<input type="submit" id="my-submit" name="sumbit" value="Get" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pete's answer here an object oriented solution:

Alex works with jQuery, so i feel free to use it in this answer.

1.
You can't call methods of a class but only methods of objects, so you have to instantiate a object of class `MicrositeRequest` somewhere. Usually you do this after the DOM is fully populated, so you write:

```
$(() => {
   new MicrositeRequest();
});
```

You may place this code beneath your class definition so that it starts after the browser loaded your script.

2.
Give your input element an id:

```
<div>
            <input id="myInputElement" type="submit" name="submit" value="Get" onclick="IsMicrositeRequestValid()" />
</div>
```

3. 

Register method `IsMicrositeRequestValid` of the `MicrositeRequest`-object as onClick-handler for your `input`-element. To achieve this add these lines to the constructor method of class `MicrositeRequest`:

```
let that = this;
$('#myInputElement').on('click', () => {
   that.IsMicrositeRequestValid();
});
```

You need variable `that` because inside the event handler `this` points to the input element.